# How to fix "call revert exception (method="tokensOfOwner(address)", errorArgs=null..." when deploying contract on Polygon

Tags: exception

I deployed on Polygon a few days ago and everything was OK.

I'm trying to do the same changing only the maximum number of NFTs available in the contract and it fails to compile:

```
$ npx hardhat run scripts/run.js --network polygon

Compiling 15 files with 0.8.4
Solidity compilation finished successfully
Contract deployed to: 0xD8F0C83513AaA3aAde3B7BF016ca999CEDe4961E
9 NFTs have been reserved

Error: call revert exception (method="tokensOfOwner(address)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:225:28)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:237:20)
at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:425:23)
at Contract. (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:392:44)
at step (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
at Object.next (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
at fulfilled (C:\Users\User\nft-collectible\node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
reason: null,
code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
method: 'tokensOfOwner(address)',
errorArgs: null,
errorName: null,
errorSignature: null,
address: '0xD8F0C83513AaA3aAde3B7BF016ca999CEDe4961E',
args: [ '0xD561Fd6763e8cc8c7603C0D7971Bc003DD2Dd17d' ],
transaction: {
data: '0x8462151c000000000000000000000000d561fd6763e8cc8c7603c0d7971bc003dd2dd17d',
to: '0xD8F0C83513AaA3aAde3B7BF016ca999CEDe4961E',
from: '0xD561Fd6763e8cc8c7603C0D7971Bc003DD2Dd17d'
}
}
```

And furher on, if I try to verify:

```
$ npx hardhat verify --network polygon 0xD8F0C83513AaA3aAde3B7BF016ca999CEDe4961E "ipfs://QmWKW6nqqHnpRoUVjnNeLE46KaDfy2oMWAysCt7qjmk8nz/"

Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The address 0xD8F0C83513AaA3aAde3B7BF016ca999CEDe4961E has no bytecode. Is the contract deployed to this network? The selected network is polygon.
```

What can it possibly be?

Comment: Could it be a gas issue? Gas was extremely high on Plolygon at the ime

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" and its linked pages along with [mcve]. Formatting is important when asking and answering on SO as it helps us help you. "[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/)"
"[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
"[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"